# Xserver on Windows7

Tags: linux, windows-7, cygwin, xserver

I have been using X11 with windows Maker provided with cygwin package for multi windows in windows Xp. Currently I am moving to windows 7 but unable to install cygwin.

Is there any other multi windowing system like windows maker for cygwin on windows ?

Thanks for your help in advance.

~ JJA

Comment: _Why_ can't you install Cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

I really like to use [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) as nice ssh client, but more importantly as very lightweight and fast X server for Windows.

Typical usage on Windows: start MobaXterm, then from its console `ssh user@linux-box`. Now, you can simply execute any GUI program on your Linux box, like `gedit`, `eclipse`, etc., and it simply works! This is because MobaXterm automatically supports forwarding of you graphical `DISPLAY` from Linux to Windows.

This method for remote access works *much* faster than VNC. Performance is actually similar to Remote Desktop, if not even faster.